# combining columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'user_a':['A','B','C',np.nan],
         'user_b':['A','B',np.nan,'D']
})
```

[image: current df]

I would like to create a new column called `user` and have the resulting dataframe:

[image: complete df]

What's the best way to do this for many `users`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use forward filling missing values and then select last column by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'user_a':['A','B','C',np.nan,np.nan],
         'user_b':['A','B',np.nan,'D',np.nan]
})

df['user'] = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
print (df)
  user_a user_b user
0      A      A    A
1      B      B    B
2      C    NaN    C
3    NaN      D    D
4    NaN    NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.apply` method:

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame({'user_a':['A','B','C',np.nan],'user_b':['A','B',np.nan,'D']})

In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
  user_a user_b
0      A      A
1      B      B
2      C    NaN
3    NaN      D

In [26]: df['user'] = df.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if not pd.isna(i)][0], axis=1)

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
  user_a user_b user
0      A      A    A
1      B      B    B
2      C    NaN    C
3    NaN      D    D
```